# Проблема с входом

Tags: linux, archlinux

Установлен Arch, окружение Xfce, настроен был автологин.
Системой долгое время не пользовался.

Возникла такая проблема - все загружается нормально, но дальше Xfce выдаёт приглашение на ввод пароля, ввожу и ничего не происходит. Т.е. ошибки, что пароль не верен, система не выдаёт, но и не логинится, всё так-же "висит" окно для ввода пароля.

Можно ли исправить, и если да, то как?

Answer (score 0):

Если используется сессия X11 / Xorg есть вероятность, что был поврежден файл /etc/X11/xorg.conf. Попробуйте его удалить (предварительно сделав копию, разумеется) после чего выполнить вход. Современные системы могут справляться без него.

Comment: Увы, уже не узнать. Развернул новую.